# insert photo to a label in javafx with a web url

Tags: image, javafx

I am currently pulling the web url of an image from facebook FQL, and would like to place this image in a label. I have tried the following but I get the error below. please help.

**CODE:**

```
String facebook_Post_Url;
Image facebook_Image = new Image(facebook_Post_Url, 700, 0, false, false);
facebook_Label.setGraphic(facebook_Image);
```

Error:

```
error: incompatible types: Image cannot be converted to Node divider1_Label.setGraphic(facebook_Image);
```

**Update:**

I tried the following code now but still get error

```
ImageView facebook_Image = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/s720x720/1508634_699393523428883_996610253_n.png")));
divider1_Label.setGraphic(facebook_Image);
```

Error:

```
Unexpected error java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = ImageViewBuilder.create().image(new Image(facebook_Post_Url)).build();       
facebook_Label.setGraphic(imageView);
```

Comment: Note:  ImageViewBuilder is now deprecated.